# How to apply count index on provider aws of terraform?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I want to create 3 ec2 instances in 3 different regions. I am using iteration and count index feature of terraform. But I am not able to apply the same feature for region parameter in aws provider.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "${element(var.region, count.index)}"
}
```

Where I am passing the values like below.

```
region = [ "us-east-1" , "eu-central-1" ]
instance_type = [ "t2.small" , "t2.micro" ]
```

I am getting following error after terraform init.

> count variables are only valid within resources

Comment: As the error message says, you can't do that. You need to specify separate aliases for each anyway.

Comment: forgot to mention, but I would like to have a generic solution. Adding aliases means hardcoding fix regions.

Comment: Yep, and unfortunately that's a limitation of Terraform. It might be better if you could expand on what your requirements are and maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: Hmm. As I have multi-region deployment so now generating separate terraform.tfvars file for each region.  
Thanks buddy @ydaetskcoR

Answer (score 0):

The region to be entered in the provider block should be your default region. Since, there is only one default region per aws user, it can't accept a list of regions.

Try giving region as:

```
region = "${var.region[0]}"
```

It takes the first element of list of regions that you have specified as variables. Accordingly, you can change the index to point to some other element of the list.

Comment: I guess this may not work. Because I have 1 terraform.tfvars file where I am mentioning a list variable of regions and I want to iterate over it.(forget about users in different we have all setup ready). For now I have created separate tfvars file for each region. 

**region = [ "us-east-1", "us-west-2", "ca-central-1"]**